# Why is "Cages & Chains: 3 of 20" in red letters?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

On the tile of my Justice screen, it says "Cages & Chains: 3 of 20", with "3 of 20" in bright-red letters. Does this mean that I need 17 more cages or chains, or is the red text not a warning?

The prison is currently empty, and has always been. There's just one crime, but no sentence pending.

Comment: Ah, Anna, you're asking all the questions I've been wondering about in my last fortress. Thanks!

Comment: There's so many knowledgeable people here!

Comment: Yeah, I love this place. I learn so much just from browsing through the questions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once again, linking from the [Wiki](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Status#Justice_Status_Screen):

> In the upper right of this screen is "Cages & Chains", which shows the total number of combined cages plus restraints designated for justice out of the total currently available. It's important to note that although it says "chains", it's counting both ropes and chains as well as cages - and ropes are not as desirable as chains when used as restraints for this purpose. If you have adequate chains and cages (at least 1 cage, rope or chain for every 10 dwarves) the number will be blue, or red if you don't have enough.

As you can see, the problem is not how many of those are free, but that you don't have enough when compared to the number of dwarves in your fortress.

Comment: Ah, I only read the "Justice" article. Thanks.